# Method naming advice required

Tags: naming, methods

My question will be about how do you think it would be fit to name some methods in a fluent interface. Let me try to demonstrate the problem.

Consider this relation tree:

[image: associations]

A person can have dogs and cats, and a dog can have bones. Pretty simple.

What i'm trying to do is create a domain specific fluent interface for determining, which ones of these relations does the user need. It is able to handle any depth of relationships.

**I designed the operation something like this** (It is building the assoicaiton tree, from which i can determine, what the user wants):
[image: association tree building]

As code (it may be more readable):

```
personAssoc = person.associate().withCats().and().withDogs().withBones().up().done();
```

But i'm trying to make this part as intuitive as possible, so i wan't the **method names** to **make sense after each other**, and **be as close to spoken language as possible**. My biggest concerns are the following 3 method names:

1. **`and()`** in my language of choice `and` is a reserved keyword, so i can't use it. I looked up synonyms (`together()`, `including()`, `also()`) but they don't sound/look right  (`and` means, that we will add more children to the parent association).
2. **`up()`** it is obviously breaking any kind of flow. With this method name, the whole thing became a lot further away from spoken language, than i wanted to (`up` means, we are not necessary wan't to add more relations to the parent, but we are done with the current one. In code it is the same as `and`).
3. **`done()`** is only called once, at the end of the method calls, but still doesn't fit the picture (`done` means, that we are literally done, we won't add more associations).

**What i'm looking for** is other, better names for the above 3, which:

1. Which make the usage of the fluent interface closer to spoken language.
2. For `and` a name, which is as far as possible from any language keywords.

If you read this whole thing, feel free to drop by any ideas, it might help me out a great deal! 
**Thank you for any suggestion.**

Comment: that looks like a horrible idea, no offense, the method names don't really relate to what it's doing, only to how good it looks being used in a particular way.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm open to anything, to make it as readable as possible. Please, if you have any suggestions, dont hold it back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here: good naming, and the abuse of fluent interfaces.

A good API has two jobs: It must be straightforward to write code using this API, and the function of the resulting code should be obvious to a reader. While fluent interfaces excel in the latter matter, languages that try to be overly English-like fail the former requirement. Any API is a language that has to be learnt, so it should be as unsurprising as possible in order for a user to learn quickly.

I would therefore suggest that you do use a fluent API, but toned down to handle only one level of hierarchy at a time:

```
Person p = makePerson()
  .with(makeDog().with(makeBone()))
  .with(makeCat())
  .finish();
```

where `PersonBuilder#with` is overloaded to handle arguments of types `Dog`, `DogBuilder`, `Cat`, and `CatBuilder` etc.

If you absolutely must use a single level, I would like to suggest `end`, `finish`, or `back` instead of `and`. Using proper indentation would also help in making the code clearer:

```
person.associate()
  .withDog()
     .withBone()
     .end()
  .end()
  .withCat()
  .end()
.end()
```

This does not make it more English-like, but it follows clear rules (any `with` is mirrored by an `end`) and looks familiar to any programmer (and especially to anyone who has seen Ruby).

Answer (score 2):

well, "with" is a awkward name... "has" is a much better one. Has and Is are very well established terms, as is Get. You should use those terms as it makes discoverability easier - people are familiar with GetParent for example as returning a parent object. This makes it a good term to keep using.

'And' seems to be "return parent", but in your naming convention, might be better described as "owner", so `getOwner()` or `whoseOwner()` might fit better.

Then you have

```
person.associate().hasCats().whoseOwner().hasDogs().hasBones().whoseOwner().disassociate()
```

disassociate seems like the opposite of associate - but both are artificial terms, it might be better to choose something less 'in keeping' with the tree and use a term that says "start processing" or similar, so you know its part of the plumbing.

Comment: I really like the `owner` thing. As for `is` and `has`, i feel like they should return a `boolean` (`true`/`false`) value, don't you think? It feels weirder for me, than `with`. For now, i leave the question open, but with owner you helped a lot, that was exactly what i was looking for to replace `and`, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

your proposed method just doesn't look maintainable to me

it's much easier to give Person a addCat and addDog method that does just that

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.addBone();
person.addDog(dog);
```

this way you can also create the dog with its bones somewhere else without passing person to the bone factory.

Comment: no no, you misunderstood the purpose of the whole thing, maybe, the name `person` is misleadig. I don't retrieve data with the method call series above, i build some kind of hierarchy-descriptor-tree, which will help me retrieve the data. So here we can't talk about concrete Dog or Person instances